# Bibliography URLs missing part when using lmodern

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, urls

I'm creating a document that contains `url`s in the bibliography. That works just fine and the urls are broken to new lines at appropriate points.

The only issue I have is that the two pdf viewers I've tested seem to crop part of the url from the end.

Example:

```
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html
```

becomes

```
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3
```

which is exactly the part before the line break.

Here is an image showing the problem (the tooltip shows the problem):

[image]

This is the latex document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % type of the document
\usepackage[english]{babel} % language of all the auto generated text
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % encoding stuff
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % encoding stuff
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % \url command
\usepackage{geometry} % define the geometry of the page
\usepackage{lmodern} % <-- THIS BREAKS IT
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=28mm, bottom=28mm} 

% the document starts here
\begin{document}

Google MarkerClusterer \cite{MarkerClusterer}.

% add the bubliography (without file extension) and style it
\bibliography{cite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

and the bib file:

```
@misc{MarkerClusterer,
    author = {},
    title = {{MarkerClusterer for Google Maps v3}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html}},
    year = {2010},
    note = {Last accessed on 2013-09-19}
}
```

I compiled with both pdflatex and lualatex.

The problem seems to be related to the `lmodern` package, since it works without it.

Does anyone know how to make the url break lines AND still make it clickable (without parts being cropped)?

Comment: The problem is not related to `lmodern`; you don't get links in the PDF unless you load `hyperref`. What you see is just a guess made by the PDF viewer based on the data it sees.

Comment: OK, so just including `hyperref` should fix it?

Comment: Yes, it will. I believe this question has already appeared, so I'm looking for a duplicate.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I was looking for the wrong cause then.